# How to save asynchronous data from Cloud Firestore as a variable?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am beginning to learn [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) using the Firebase SDK on Android, and I have run into an issue where I retrieve data from the Firestore database through an OnCompleteListener and then try to save it as a variable. The issue is that after the OnCompleteListener ends and my Android App moves on to the next line of code, the data in the variable is reset and not saved.

I have a collection of users and am trying to retrieve a user's sport for the user's season:

```
db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("seasons").document(seasonName)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document != null && document.exists() && document.getData() != null) {
                                sport = String.valueOf(document.getData().get("sport"));
                                //sport is set to the value
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        //Now sport is null
```

The sport is set to the value in the listener, but then goes to null after the listener completes.

So my question is, how can I save the variable permanently so that it doesn't go back to null? Is there a way to retrieve the data without a listener so I won't have this problem, or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable isn't "going back" to null.  The issue is that the listener you added is being invoked some unknown amount of time after the query finishes.  You don't know how long it's going to take.  Because the time is unknown, the a Task is returned immediately by `get()`, and the callbacks you attach to it will be invoked some time later.  Since `get()` returns immediately, the variable `sport` will retain its individual value of null until the callback is invoked.  This means that you should only use the results from within the callback.  Or, if you want to store it somewhere, only access it when you are sure the callback has been invoked.

In fact, all Firebase APIs are asynchronous.  [Read this](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93) to learn why.  You should become familiar with asynchronous programming in order to use Firebase SDKs.

For Android specifically, [you should learn how the Play Services Task API works](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).

Comment: Is there any way I can wait for the listener to finish and then set the variable?

Comment: The listener *is* waiting for the query to finish. You have to use that mechanism.